# Javascript to determine page types with Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, arrays, wordpress

I'm sure this is elementary but I've been tasked with the following for a wordpress website.

How can I find this information?

---

Determining the page type (Home page, Article, Section front etc.):
Format:

JS array: Structure of an array item–
{“Type”: “name of type”, Expression: “JS expression”}

JS expression should return Boolean value. (Should return true, if a current page has this type)

Order of times in the array is priority.
Examples:

```
Determining the page type (Home page, Article, Section front etc.):
```

Format:
JS array: Structure of an array item–
{“Type”: “name of type”, Expression: “JS expression”}
JS expression should return Boolean value. (Should return true, if a current page has this type)
Order of times in the array is priority.

Examples:

```html
[
  {
    "Type": "Home page",
    "Expression": location.pathname == "/"
  },
  {
    "Type": "Section",
    "Expression": contentData.type == "Section"
  },
  {
    "Type": "Article",
    "Expression": isArticlePage()
  },
]
```

This is for some newsletters in wordpress to be set up.  Thanks for any info on how to do this on a site like [www.recordherald.com](http://www.recordherald.com).

thanks!
Doug

Comment: We need to know more about your WP setup to be able to tell you how to do this. These open graph types aren't added to WP by default. However they can be added by certain plugins in your site so you might have a plugin that is adding them to the meta data, or you might need to install one. Can you confirm if you have the OG information in your web page head?

Answer (score 0):

Most Wordpress installations put the page type into `og:type` meta tag, which you can read with the following Javascript:

```
const pageType = document.head.querySelector("[property~='og:type'][content]").content;
console.log(pageType);
```

A better way would be to explicitly print the type into a Javascript variable using PHP and Wordpress functions.

```
echo json_encode(['pageType' => $pageType]);
```

Comment: Adding open graph tags such as `og:type` isn't a default feature of WP. Some popular plugins can add it, but its not part of WP so we cannot assume it will exist. I think this should be mentioned here because even if the OP does have them in their site (and we don't know for sure because they have only asked about sites *like* the one they include), other users looking for help might not.